# MATLAB - Binning Data

Tags: matlab

I have a large data set and I'm trying to bin the data in increments of 100. I know how to bin data in 100 equal sized bins, but I haven't had any luck specifying a range I would like the data binned in. Anyone have any tips on how to do this? I'd also like to be able to label the bins instead of just having bin 1,2,3, etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[`discretize`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/discretize.html) was written for this. You can specify edges directly. From mathworks:

```
X = 1:2:21;
edges = primes(21);
Y = discretize(X,edges)
```

edit: I believe you can reach the same result using [`histcounts`](http://[N,edges]%20=%20histcounts(X,edges)):

```
[N,edges] = histcounts(X,edges)
```

Comment: Please note that this function was Introduced in R2015a